# Converting a complicated list of matrices into an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix

I would like to convert a list of matrices into an array of stapled matrices. My list looks like `l3` in:

```
  getme<-matrix(1,3,3)
  getme2<-matrix(2,4,4)
  l1<-list(getme,getme2)
  names(l1)<-c('getme','getme2')
  getme<-matrix(3,3,3)
  getme2<-matrix(4,4,4)
  l2<-list(getme,getme2)
  names(l2)<-c('getme','getme2')
  l3<-list(l1,l2)
```

The goal is to append each conformable matrix into an array. The name of the array/variable should be equal to the name of the level of the list.

So for example:

```
  getme<-array(dim=c(3,3,2))
  m=2
  for(i in 1:m){getme[,,i]<-l3[[i]]$getme}
```

Since my lists get vary large in terms of both `m`and number of `getme`matrices, I need to automatize this procedure across all `m` levels of the list `l3`. Ideally I would want code that produces `j` arrays `getme`, `getme2`,...`getme_j`, where only `l3`is used as an input. That is the names of the variable levels, `names(l3[[1]])`, are applied on the way.

Comment: A nitpick from Mr.Math:  "complex" != "complicated"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I adjusted the title to complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of matrices into arrays is easy with `abind` from the `abind` package:

```
library(abind)
res <- lapply(seq_along(l3[[1]]), function(x) 
                                    abind(lapply(l3, "[[", x), along = 3))
```

The outer `lapply` function is used to apply a function to the numbers form 1 to the length of the list `l3`. The current number is represented by parameter `x`. The other `lapply` command is used to extract the `x`th element from the list `l3`. These elements are combined into an array with `abind`. Since the length of `l3` is `2`, the outer `lapply` returns a list of length `2`.

This returns a list of arrays:

```
[[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3


[[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4    4
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

You can use the original names with

```
names(res) <- names(l3[[1]])
```

Comment: I do not understand why it works and how it works, but it works.